What Spring controller method return type to use If I want to return type X or Y depending on condition?
I want to create method in Spring controller that returns String or SseEmitter depending on condition.
What return type I should specify in method signature?
@GetMapping("/test")
public WHAT_TO_WRITE_HERE test() {
    if (MyCondition) {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        //Fill SseEmitter with data, not related to question
        return emitter;
    } else {
        return "String";
    }
}


The method could be made void, and use the underlying response stream and write directly.    Or use a composite to return a String or an SseEmitter. But I doubt an SseEmitter could be sent in an HTTP response.  Is this a toy example?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Appears to be an XY problem.


Can you show example of composite type that can be returned from spring controller? I would prefer this approach to changing method return type to void because then signature of method will be more informative.
This is toy example, but SseEmitter can be sent as HTTP response in real application.
I want to receive HTTP request, accomplish some task, in case of error respond with String, in case of success respond with SseEmitter.


You shouldn't do it because it will confuse the API clients.
But say you want to do it for testing purposes.
Then, you can simply set an Object as a return type.
Here is an example
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DemoController {


    @GetMapping("/demo")
    public Object demo() {
        if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
            return "Hello, World!";
        } else {
            return new User("John Doe", "test@gmail.com");
        }
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class User {
    private String name;
    private String email;
}

Depending on condition, the endpoint will return
GET http://localhost:8080/api/demo

HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 21 Jun 2024 05:20:41 GMT

{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "email": "test@gmail.com"
}

or
GET http://localhost:8080/api/demo

HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 13
Date: Fri, 21 Jun 2024 05:24:56 GMT

Hello, World!


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You wouldn't. What you are trying to do goes against REST standards. You'd break  every REST client out there that would need special handling for your API.
Following the REST API standard, your method returns SseEmitter. A success would get translated by the framework to 200 OK and return your object serialized to JSON. If there's an error, you'd throw a ResponseStatusException and put the status code and the error message in there which would get translated properly and the status code and error message would be where clients expect it.
